# file reading in python, need help for homework

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function func(infilepath) that reads the file whose file path is infilepath, and prints the number of times each character(excluding newline characters) appeared in the file, in sorted order of the characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Post code first.

Comment: I would if I had any, but no clue on how to start..

Comment: [Google is for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=file+read+python).

Comment: There's lots of info/tutorials on Google/YouTube on how to read files in python. You should check those out, then come here if you can't figure something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be the exact answer, but enough to get you started!

First, open a file:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
```

Then read lines

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

Define a dictionary. Split the line by spaces, increment the dictionary by one if they character is already present in the dictionary, else initialize it to 0.

```
chars = {}
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
for line in lines:
    line = line.split(" ")
    for i in line:
        if i not in chars.keys():
            chars[i] = 0
        else:
            chars[i]+=1
```

More about file handling: https://github.com/thewhitetulip/build-app-with-python-antitextbook/blob/master/manuscript/06-file-handling.md

More about sets/lits/dictionaries: https://github.com/thewhitetulip/build-app-with-python-antitextbook/blob/master/manuscript/04-list-set-dict.md

Some practical examples to get you thinking: https://github.com/thewhitetulip/build-app-with-python-antitextbook/blob/master/manuscript/13-examples.md